# Meaning of Options in FastBoot Flash Menu

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot

I've just bought my first Android device, a Motorola Moto G. Following the official guide on Motorola website, I learnt about FastBoot Flash Menu. Here there are several options. I'd like to know what everyone means.

[image: Fastboot Flash Mode]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what all of them mean but I can get you started. You are currently in the bootloader.

**Recovery**: This is the partition in memory that has a recovery installed. A recovery program allows you to connect via adb (android debug bridge), flash update zip files (or ROMs), perform backups (nandroid backups), wipe data, factory reset the phone and some other stuff.

**Factory**: This option will restore your phone to factory settings. In other words, it will wipe all your data and the phone will start back up like it was new.

That's all I know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you said about Factory is wrong, it does not reset the phone, it is apparently more like a "factory mode" for the manufacturer, but I don't know exactly.